# Update ComboBox list in Realtime

Tags: c#

I have a ComboBox automatically list all the HTML files located in the same directory as my application. But I can't figure out how to update the Combobox in realtime while the application is running if a new HTML file is added to the directory.

```
string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.html");
foreach (string file in filePaths)
{
    HTMLFiles.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(file));
}
```

How can I update this to add new HTML files in realtime?

Comment: [FileSystemWatcher Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Are you struggling with getting the list of files, or the presentation of the file names in a combobox?  If the latter are you using WPF, WinForms, etc?